# Most performant way to add to DOM in ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, ngfor

I have a websocket and bound to an ngFor which displays data. List size is approximately 100 records.

I have created a button on each entry, and attached a click method which creates a loading `div`/spinner on click whilst some other logic is performed. Once the method is complete, i delete the 'loading' `div` from the button/DOM.

I have achieved this via d3. Question/s are:

1. Is this the most efficient/correct way to do this?
2. I have read of ViewChild and Renderer. Should I be using that?

I made the decision to add the loading/spinner div dyanmically, rather than add to the DOM/HTML if not needed.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zenqoe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproduct-list%2Fproduct-list.component.ts

html:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let product of products">

    <h3>
      <a [title]="product.name + ' details'">
        {{ product.name }}
      </a>
    </h3>

    <button (click)="share(product)" id="btn-{{product.id}}">
      Share
    </button>

  </li>
</ul>
```

component:

```
share(product) {
    window.alert(product.id);

    const btn = d3.select('#btn-' + product.id)

    btn.append('div')
    .class({'my-class': true})
    .text('Loading...');

    // Some extra logic
    // After logic is completed (via its .subscribe) remove element

    setTimeout(function(){   

       let divv = document.getElementById('btn-' + product.id)
       divv.remove()

    }, 3000); 

   
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Multiple event will registered for each element of ngFor.
Use Event bubbling for for registering on parent div and passing the child id to it for single event registration.